# PHP read csv file through http request

Tags: php, csv, binary

I'm making an API where the user sends an CSV to my page in binary code.
I need to read that CSV and read all rows in that CSV.
Inside that loop I'm adding each row to the DB.
I don't know how to do that.

Currently I'm using `fgetcsv` but that function can't be used to read binary files.
Thats only used for Posting CSV files in a POST.
I'm sending a CSV file through a HTTP request.
My result looks like this:
"person 1", "street 4", "test@gmail.com",,, "florida", "person 2", "street 5", "test2@gmail.com",,, "florida"

Comment: Can you post an example of a couple of lines of the *binary CSV* as I'm not sure what it is or how to read it?  Does it have some form of delimiter or is it more a fixed format.

Comment: Its a fixed format, the file is send through http request as binary, but I receive it as comma seperated list. I would like to know how many rows there are an loop through them

Comment: @NigelRen updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over each line and data in there you can use this format:

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $data); // split the string by new lines
foreach($lines as $line){ // Loop over each line
    $column = explode(",", $line); // split the line in 'columns'
    $name = $column[0];
    $street = $column[1]; 
}
```

Comment: What If I don't have comma's but "person1""street 1""test@gmail.com" ??

Comment: Split the columns using the 2 double quotes like this: explode("\"\"", $line); Make sure to escape them with backslashes. Then remove the double quotes at the end and beginning using string replace or substr.